# Problema na instalação do Bower no windows

Tags: windows, node.js, bower

Eu instalei sem problemas o nodejs. Rodei esse comando e foi:

```
npm -v
1.4.28
```

Logo após eu tento instalar o bower e não consigo:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Depois de rodar esse comando aparece isso: Não faço a minima ideia do que seja (já instalei varias vezes em outros computadores e nunca deu esse error)

[image: Error ao installar o bower no windows]

Como resolvo isso?

**UPDATE**: Não aparece mais error na hora de instalar mais o commando do bower ele não funciona:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente, o erro está que você está tentando instalar programas como um usuário normal.

No caso do Windows, você tem que executar o `command prompt` como um administrador para realizar essa operação.

## EDIT

Aparentemente o `bower` não está no `PATH` do sistema. Faça o seguinte:

1. Edite o arquivo de inicialização do bash (`/.bashrc`);
2. No arquivo editado, escreva `PATH="$PATH":path/pasta/bin/do/bower`;
3. Exporte o `PATH`, ainda no mesmo arquivo (`EXPORT $PATH;`);
4. Salve e feche o arquivo;
5. Abra uma nova janela do terminal;
6. Verifique o comando `bower -v`.

[Fonte das instruções](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: Abri o cmd do windows como administrador e rodei o mesmo código não deu nenhum erro, mas agora eu tento ver se o bower foi instalado `bower -v` e diz o que o comando não foi encontrado

Comment: Você tentou reiniciar o computador depois?

Comment: Sim, e continua dando `Command not found`

Comment: Atualize a pergunta com o novo erro.

Comment: Pronto coloquei um print do que está acontecendo

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Não conseguir fazer do jeito que você falou. Eu acessei o painel de controle e coloquei no path isso:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local;C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower`

Comment: Só não tenha apagado o PATH todo ao escrever isso. Mas deve ter funcionado, creio eu.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19747/discussion-between-mutley-and-salatiel-queiroz).